# como puedo hacer para que mi código envíe varias imágenes?

Tags: whatsapp

```
import pywhatkit
from Important import MobileNo
import os  # Import the 'os' module
from PIL import Image

Msg = "Hola Soy el bot de prueba"

# Define MobileNo here if not defined elsewhere
MobileNo = "+525565146551"

# Correct the variable name from iamgePath to imagePath
imagePath = "Broly.png"

Caption = "Soy el Sayayin más fuerte del universo"

# Use the correct pywhatkit function for sending the image
# pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg(MobileNo, Msg, 13, 39, 10)

pywhatkit.sendwhats_image(MobileNo, imagePath, Caption, 15)

# Rest of your code...

def list_images_in_folder(folder_path):
    image_extensions = ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif', '.bmp']

    image_files = []
    for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if any(file.lower().endswith(ext) for ext in image_extensions):
            image_files.append(os.path.join(folder_path, file))

    return image_files

if __name__ == "__main__":
    folder_path = "C:\\proyectos"
    image_files = list_images_in_folder(folder_path)

    if not image_files:
        print("No se encontraron imágenes en la carpeta.")
    else:
        print("Imágenes encontradas:")
        for image_file in image_files:
            print(image_file)
```

Estoy tratando de programar un bot que envie diferentes imágenes automáticamente cada 180 minutos y que se ejecute por si mismo...
Alguien del foro podría explicarme como es que puedo realizar o modificar mi código por favor?
se los agradecería mucho.
Así mismo mi inquietud es prácticamente como enviar más de tres imágenes obviamente de las mismas características y de manera automática.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y que se supone que esta mal con este codigo?

Comment: de paso... supongo es python no??? porque whatsapp no es ningun lenguaje...